# Using RequireJS/Backbone.js and gathering errorception with sufficient information

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

We are starting to use RequireJS and Backbone.js. However, it is also important to gather errors that happen in production. For that we use errorception. We found that we don't get the stacktrace. Does anybody know of a way to fix that?

Comment: do you normally get stacktraces? The [errorception faq](https://errorception.com/faq) says stacktraces are normally not accessible.

Comment: I should update the FAQ, but stack traces are now available in modern browsers by default: http://blog.errorception.com/2013/10/stack-traces-windowonerror-and-future.html Which browser are you not seeing stack traces with?

Comment: @RakeshPai, sorry for the false alarm, as I wrote in my answer, I've tested sending an error to errorception from an application that uses RequireJS and Backbone.js in an incorrect way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this was a false alarm. The reason that errorception did not show a stacktrace for a test that I did was because I executed:

```
throw 'foo bar';
```

The correct way was supposed to be:

```
throw new Error('foo bar');
```

I then tried to execute the following code without defining the variable `a`:

```
if (a === 5) {
  console.log('Should not come here.');
}
```

And there was the stacktrace in errorception. We've been using errorception for quite some time now and it is very helpful.

Comment: Ah sweet. :) Related, so might be a good read: http://www.devthought.com/2011/12/22/a-string-is-not-an-error/